# asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How do I determine which SELECT button was clicked in a GridView?

The multiple SELECT buttons will be used for an application approval process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Grid's Builtin Command buttons that you can easily recognize them using command name property of GridView_ItemCommand event of the grid.

Comment: I use link buttons. Then how can I get the selected row's index?

Comment: @Rauf Nicole: Then you can use GridView_ItemDataBound to set the Link's href to a different request/url or same url with different query string i.e. http://www.example.com/myPage.aspx?action=1&val=5 for the first row, http://www.example.com/myPage.aspx?action=2&val=6 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `RowCommand` event from the `GridView` and handle the click from a button. On the button, you can set `CommandArgument` if you need to pass any data from the grid to the handler.